# Rails validate collection_select doesn't display error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I have a simple `has_many :through` relationship and want to validate that at least two associated records are selected when creating a `Course`. `Student`s are enrolled in the `Course` through the `EnrollmentAssignment` association. I want to select students to enroll in the `Course` form, and validate that there are at least 2 students selected. I'm using [simple form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) which handles generating the actual HTML/CSS for validation errors, so it may be something to tweak in that library/configuration, or it may be a bug with the library.

**Course**

```rb
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollment_assignments,
           class_name: 'EnrollmentAssignment',
           foreign_key: 'course_id'
  has_many :students,
           through: :enrollment_assignments

  validate :students_selected

  def students_selected
    self.errors.add(:student_ids,  "select at least 2 students") if student_ids.size < 2
  end
end
```

**EnrollmentAssignment**

```rb
class EnrollmentAssignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student
end
```

**Student**

```rb
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollment_assignments,
           class_name: 'EnrollmentAssignment',
           foreign_key: 'student_id'
  has_many :courses,
           through: :enrollment_assignments
end
```

And now the HTML form field(Slim markup, but you get the idea):

```rb
= f.collection_select(:student_ids, students, :id, :name,
        {include_blank: false, :include_hidden => false, :selected => @course.students.map(&:id)},
        {:multiple => true})
```

I want to validate that there are at least 2 students selected. The custom validation works, because I get error output when I inspect the object on validation failure:

```rb
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fe70e058500
 @base=
  #<Course:0x007fe70c0813f8
   id: nil,
   name: "Whatever",
   created_at: nil,
   updated_at: nil>,
 @details=
  {:student_ids=>[{:error=>"select at least 2 students"}]},
 @messages=
  {:student_ids=>["select at least 2 students"]}>
```

However, the error doesn't actually display in the form. The form select HTML is this:

```html
<select multiple="" name="course[student_ids][]" id="course_student_ids">
    <option value="1">Student 1</option>
    <option value="2">Student 2</option>
</select>
```

A proper invalid HTML input looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group string required course_name form-group-invalid">
    <label class="form-control-label string required" for="course_name">Name <abbr title="required">*</abbr></label>
    <input class="form-control is-invalid string required" type="text" value="" name="course[name]" id="course_name">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Name can't be blank</div>
</div>
```

The parameters come through fine (even in strong parameters), it's just that the form won't actually display the error. Other fields have their validations shown no problem, it's just this select field that won't display properly. I imagine that it has something to do with the fact that it's a `collection_select`. I appreciate any help in resolving this issue!

Comment: I'm sorry. There's a lot there. Where do you actually output the errors?

Comment: @jvillian Second code block from the bottom. There isn't an actual "error" like system error, function error, it's a validation error for my Rails model that isn't displaying properly in the HTML form. The field is validated properly (can be seen in the code block with `ActiveModel::Errors`, second from the bottom), but the validation won't show up in the HTML form. That's where I'm having problems.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Where is the `slim` code in your view that places the validation error on the page?

Comment: @jvillian I edited the question to improve clarity. It might be an issue with the HTML form library I'm using (SimpleForm). I've added an example of how the HTML should look as well.

Comment: @jvillian Actually it turns out I just needed to fix my form to use the proper SimpleForm helper instead of Rails' `collection_select` so that SimpleForm would also pick up the errors. It's all fixed now, I'm going to delete my question in an hour!

Comment: I wish I had a dime for every SimpleForm question...

Comment: @jvillian Haha yeah I've had my fair share of headaches trying to get the library to do what I want it to... but all in all I think it has saved me much more time than writing HTML forms from scratch, so definitely worth it in my opinion :P